# Should A Big Parasol on a Decidueye Protect me from Dragapult VMAX Shred

Tags: pokemon

Can anyone help clear up an discussion I'm having with my son as to whether a big parasol stops a dragapult's shred getting through Deep Forest Camo.

The Text on Decidueye's Deep Forest Camo ability is:

> Prevent all damage done to this Pokémon by attacks from your opponent’s Pokémon V and Pokémon-GX.

The text on Big Parasol is:

> As long as the Pokémon this card is attached to is in the Active Spot, prevent all effects of attacks from your opponent’s Pokémon done to all of your Pokémon. (Existing effects are not removed. Damage is not an effect.)

And the text on Dragapult VMAX's Shred Attack is:

> This attack’s damage isn’t affected by any effects on your opponent’s Active Pokémon.

So does the big parasol prevent the effect of the attack that is it's ability to get through effects? My assumption is no as "Damage is not an effect" but my son's point is that the effect is that it ignores effects.  I can see what he's getting at but as shred would ignore other tool cards (e.g. Hard Charm) I can't see that the big parasol should stop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer: Dragapult VMax's attack goes through.

The way to understand it:  Big Parasol puts a "shield" on the Pokémon, so that it doesn't allow anything other than damage go through that shield. That's great!  But in this case, that's all that is being passed: damage.  Decidueye's ability ("prevent all damage done to this Pokémon...") is an effect on Decidueye, and it (attempts to) affect something to the damage being dealt to Decidueye ... but it doesn't actually work, due to Dragapult VMax's attack text that says to ignore that effect. Big Parasol doesn’t come into play.

Comment: If anyone remembers where the Compendium references are for this, please feel free to edit them in - I can't find them, as they're under something else (Big Parasol has one entry, but it's not relevant).

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct- Draga's dmg from shred hits Decidueye. Their explanation isn't quite right, though. Deep Forest Camo puts an effect on Deci, not the attacker. Deci gets two shields when it has a Big Parasol- now V damage AND effects from attacks can't hit it.

The rub is that Draga VMAX's Shred attack doesn't affect Decidueye- it affects what it says on the card "*the damage from this attack*" is the subject of the sentence, so that's what's being affected. Big Parasol says prevent effects done "*to your pokemon*" Shred has an effect done to its own damage.

Comment: Yes, you’re right … didn’t explain it very well back then!! Adjusted the wording some. I find it very hard to explain Shred interactions satisfactorily even though I know how they work…