# Can Big Parasol Item card stop Regidrago VStar's one attack?

Tags: pokemon

I feel like my awnser was in this post but just wanna check.
[Should A Big Parasol on a Decidueye Protect me from Dragapult VMAX Shred](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/56564/should-a-big-parasol-on-a-decidueye-protect-me-from-dragapult-vmax-shred)

Me and a friend have been discussing that if the opponent's active pokemon has a big parasol tool card on it Regidrago VStar's Apex Dragon move just does nothing now.

And for context Big Parasol

**As long as the Pokémon this card is attached to is in the Active Spot, prevent all effects of attacks from your opponent's Pokémon done to all of your Pokémon (Existing effects are not removed. Damage is not an effect.)**

Then Apex Dragon for Regidrago VStar

**Choose an attack from a Dragon Pokémon in your discard pile and use it as this attack.**

I think it should still be able to work just if the move it uses does any other effect other then damage it does it doesn't do those effects just does the damage. But maybe I am wrong. I feel the one answer I skimmed over form the other post the best way to think of big parasol is a shield for effects for you Pokemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  Big Parasol protects the Pokémon it is attached to from the effects of attacks, like a shield; it does not affect the attacking Pokemon at all. Regidrago VStar’s attack Apex Dragon’s text doesn’t pass through that shield - it only impacts Regidrago VStar until the attack starts actually doing something to the opponent (after the attack to use is selected).